# Javascript window.open function to open all urls in a json feed

Tags: javascript, function, extjs, cordova, window.open

I really hope somebody will be able to point me in the right direction with this, sp thanks in advance : )

I'm needing to take what comes in on a json feed and use some javascript to take embedded links - I was getting then by document.getElementsByTagName - and convert them into a window.open function.

I've got so far with

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var len = links.length;

for(var i=0; i<len; i++)
{
    links[i].target = "_blank";
}
```

This adds a location onto my url, but actually what I really need to do is take all url a href stings like

```
<a href="http://myurl.com"</a>
```

and return them in plain javascript to call a function

```
window.open('http://myurl.com', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

Hope that makes sense, and thanks for some newbie help.
Allister

**A bit more...**

Karaxuna - thanks for your suggestion. though for some reason the loop function didn't return what I needed, but that's probably because of how I'm trying to use it.

I'm actually trying to get something working for Phonegap for a mobile browser call, using the inappbrowser function for all my links so that they open within the app webview, not the system browser. For that all my links need to be launched by function
window.open('http://myurl.com', '_blank', 'location=yes');

I'm using sencha touch to create a list item tap that takes content from a json feed and my code looks like

```
onMylistItemTap: function(dataview, index, target, record, e, eOpts) {
    dataview.up().push({
        xtype: 'panel',
        html: [ 
        "<div class='news_story'>" +
        "   <h4>" + record.get('title') + "</h4>" +
        "   <img src='" + record.get('mobile_url') + "' />" +
        "   <span>" + record.get('content') + "</span>" +
        "</div>"
        ],
        id: 'NewsDetailCard',
        scrollable: {
            direction: 'vertical',
            directionLock: true
        }
    });
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    var len = links.length;

    for(var i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        links[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
            window.open(this.href, '_blank', 'location=yes');
            return false;
        });
    }

},
```

However, I'm not getting links opened with the click function you've added. Not sure what's wrong.
Allister

Comment: as a general remark - i think most browsers should (and will) prevent opening too many new windows from javascript in a loop. You should probably also have an eye on that behaviour and if it could affect you with your number of opening windows.

Comment: Are there any js errors?

Comment: Just deleted my previous comment! Sorry, i never noticed your update (new to stackoverflow!). Worked perfectly THANKYOU!

Comment: Now that I've got all my ahref links working with this funciton, I've realised that I now have to treat mailto tags differently as they still need to open within the system to be dealt with by the device's mail programme. Is there an easy way to exclude mailto: references from the function?

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var i=0; i<len; i++)
{
    links[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
        window.open(this.href, '_blank', 'location=yes');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

Comment: Updated the question below